# What does 2>&1 do to popen?

Tags: c, popen

`2>&1` causes `popen` to trap the `stderr`.

I want to understand how does it work.

What roles do 2, >, &, 1 play here?
What do I need to study to understand them?

Comment: i think this is a good start for learning about fd redirection: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: @Naytzyrhc add that as an answer with some details.

Comment: [Here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a shell construct. It means redirect (`>`) *stderr*(`2`) to wherever *stdout*(`1`) goes. `1` is file the `stdout`'s file descriptor and `2` is the `stderr`'s file descriptor.

```
$ command 2>&1 #redirect stderr to stdout

$ command 1>&2 #redirect stdout to stderr

$ command 1>output 2>errors #redirect stdout to a file called "output"
                            #redirect stderr to a file called "errors"
```

`popen()` captures only `stdout`. So running a command using can't capture the messages from its `stderr`.

For example, with

```
  FILE *fp = popen("command", "r");
```

only `stdout` of `command` can be captured (read using `fp`). But with this

```
  FILE *fp = popen("command 2>&1", "r");
```

`stdout` and `stderr` are captured. But with this redirection, `stdout` is indistinguishable from `stderr` as they both are mixed.

---

The effect is doing same as [`dup2(1,2);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) in C.

Consider

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
   dup2(1,2);
   fprintf(stdout, "printed to stdout\n");
   fprintf(stderr, "printed to stderr\n");
}
```

If this is compiled and run as:

```
# ./a.out >output
```

Both lines will be printed to a file called `output`.

If run the code by commenting out the `dup2()` line. Now only the first line will be printed to the file and second line will be printed on the console even it captures only the `stdout` using redirection (`>`).

Additional sources:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html
- https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 2):

it's a basic file descriptor redirect. It redirects everything from `stderr` (`2`) into (`>`) the file descriptor of `stdout` (`&1`).

A nice thing is you can also redirect stdout to somewhere else at the same time.
E.g.:

```
command >some-file 2>&1
```

For more information about file descriptor redirection (in unix/linux), I recommend https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) say:

> To find File.txt, and then redirect handle 1 (that is, STDOUT) and
>   handle 2 (that is, STDERR) to the Search.txt, type: findfile
>   file.txt>search.txt 2<&1

Also

```
/* Standard file descriptors.  */
#define STDIN_FILENO    0   /* Standard input.  */
#define STDOUT_FILENO   1   /* Standard output.  */
#define STDERR_FILENO   2   /* Standard error output.  */
```

You can also refer the [2.7 Redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07) to get the details for it.

*Links for further study:*

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html